# conda: fastqc package exists, but 'fastqc' is not recognized as a command

Tags: package, conda

I couldn't find the answer in the previous topics, so have to ask this question.
I'm very fresh in working with conda. I've just installed fastqc using conda on Windows 10 (x64) desktop along with openjdk package.
I can see it in the list of installed packages when using `conda list`. But when I call the program by the relevant command, for example, `fastqc *.gz -t 4`, I'm getting the error that

**'fastqc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Any idea why that happens and how to fix that ?
Thanks a lot for the help!
Evgenii

Comment: Please search this site for the exact error message **not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**. This question has been asked and answered literally hundreds of times before.

Comment: Thank you, the question was more fastqc specific. Looks like it just doesn't work properly on Win machines. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bioconda does not support Windows. Despite being a `noarch` package and running on Java (platform independent), the entry point is an executable Perl script that relies on a shebang to identify `perl` as the interpreter. Windows doesn't support shebangs, hence the issue.

I recommend Windows users that wish to use Bioconda to set up WSL2 and install a Linux version of Mambaforge.